# how a contract with only interface (no implementation) being called by another contract?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

I have seen several examples, in the example they defined a contract shown below

```
contract ForeignToken {
    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool);
}
```

And in another contract, they used the previous defined ForeignToken.

```
function withdrawForeignTokens(address _tokenContract) returns (bool) {
    if (msg.sender != owner) { throw; }

    ForeignToken token = ForeignToken(_tokenContract);

    uint256 amount = token.balanceOf(address(this));
    return token.transfer(owner, amount);
}
```

I can't understand how the second contract could use the balanceOf and transfer function, since I assume the ForeignToken doesn't see implement any interface or has its own implementations.

the code example is seen in both

https://github.com/jkeesh/dogetoken/blob/master/contracts/contract.sol

and

https://etherscan.io/address/0xe531642e9bb5d027e9c20e03284287b97919a9a5#code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the whole point of interfaces, it makes it easy to call functions on other contracts without having to know all the contract code.

This line:

```
  ForeignToken token = ForeignToken(_tokenContract);
```

Is assuming that the contract at `_tokenContract` is a contract which *implements* the `ForeignToken` interface. So when it calls this function:

```
 token.balanceOf(address(this));
```

it has no way of knowing (and no real need to know) how the `balanceOf` function works internally. But assuming the `token` contract has implemented `ForeignToken` interface, it knows that it will return a `uint256`.

Different impementations of `ForeignToken` could work differently, but by declaring `token` as an instance of `ForeignToken`, it means the person who wrote the second contract can use the `token.balanceOf` method in their contract and the compiler won't have an issue with it.